# The call stack displayed by context record is not present in any threads

Tags: windbg

After switching the context using the **.cxr** command and listing the call stack using **kv** command I noticed that none of the thread have similar call stack.
Does anyone know why this happens? Is it because the dump file is correupted.

Note: The dump file was a miniDump file generated on x64 Win7 machine.

Comment: Could you put the output from your erroneous call stack and also a sample call stack from a correct one, otherwise we cannot really tell you what is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The call stack dispayed after a .cxr shows the actual stack at the time when the context record was made.

Its perfectly normal that this stack don’t exist at a later time.
If the content of the context record is rubbish, the stack is also nonsense.
If the context record is on the stack, you can reveal which thread it belongs using

```
!address <context record>
```

Comment: But this was an application crash. So shouldn't atleast 1 thread contain similar call stack?

Comment: Are you sure that you have the context record related to the crash?
Can you tell how you acquired the address used in .cxr !

Comment: The dump is generated by our own internal tool. Once the dump is opened in WinDBG it tells us where the context record is located.

And ya I am sure the context record is related to the crash.

Comment: Then I will encourage you to post your stacks, ~* e kv is handy for dumping stack for all threads